# conversion of "in order to" to a "because" subclause

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Clauses with "in order to" can be converted to clauses with "because" by adding a verb that indicates necessity or desire.

Does this statement always hold? (if not please provide a counter example, if yes please provide a reference)

Examples:

"I wake up at 6, in order to catch the 7AM bus" -> "I wake up at 6, **because** I **want/need** to catch the 7AM bus"

"In order to make tea, I need water" -> "**Because** I **want** to make tea, I need water"

"In order to succeed, you must work hard" -> "**Because** you **must** succeed, you must work hard"

Comment: When you see a statement like this in a grammar book, always add _in some circumstances_ after _can_. I.e, these statements express possible uses, but are stated like universal rules and therefore do not, as a rule, always hold, in every context. A good grammar book will detail the obligatory, optional, and forbidden contexts, and the reasons -- as far as they are known -- for them.

Comment: You forgot to mention the idea that this is one way only. That is, **in order to** can be transformed to **because**, but not always the other way around.

Comment: You might want to add the following to your Question to show the cross reference: For reference, this question was motivated by [CoolHandLouis' comment](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/22934/how-to-ask-a-question-according-to-the-specific-sections#comment-43268) to [@msam's answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/22966/3796) on ell.se. You might also want to add a cross reference to your answer on ell.se back to here as well.

Comment: @JohnLawler I have no doubt that it can hold in some circumstances, I was wondering if it held in all of them (this is an "out of interest" not a "would it be right if I said that" question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Because* indicates reason, not (primarily) purpose:

> The buildings were destroyed in the earthquake because they were so
>   flimsy.
>
> I shouted at him because I wanted him to stop slapping her. [there is
>   a purpose, but the purpose (achieving the cessation of hostilities) is
>   the reason for the shouting]

*In order to* indicates purpose [and thus intelligent agency]:

> XXX The buildings were built flimsily in order to be liable to collapse ... XXX
>
> I shouted at him in order to try to get him to stop slapping her.
>   [just the purpose highlighted]

Reasons don't necessarily imply purpose [what an intelligent agent is out to achieve], but purpose is always a (potential) reason. So a 'because ...' clause will always be available for an 'in order to' construction. Whether it means exactly the same thing (in terms of the feasibility of the action) is debatable.

[B] "Because I want to make tea, I need water" is not exactly the same as [A] 'In order to make tea, I need water". A desire does not translate directly to a need. [C] "Because I want to make tea, I would like to have some water" or [D] "Because I am going to make tea, I will need some water" sound better than [B] to me.

Comment: [D] does sound better but I was trying to keep the structure as much as possible and not modify the main clause at all rather than try to find out what sounds better. My take is that "in order to" sounds more generic than the versions with "because": "I need water" -> why? -> "In order to make tea" / "Because I want/[B]need/have/would like to make tea". The usage of want vs need etc. differentiates the meaning while with "in order to" we don't really know if it's a need or desire.

Comment: Regarding [C], "In order to make tea, I would like to have some water" -> "Because I want/wish/etc. to make tea, I would like to have some water" (again trying to keep the main clause unchanged).

Comment: Another problem is that the non-finite clause in 'In order to make tea, I would like to have some water' wrongly modifies 'I'. In 'I would like to have some water, in order to make tea' doesn't work for me either, compare 'I have some water, in order to make tea'. I'm happy with 'I got some water, in order to make tea'. It's the getting of the water that has purpose, not the having it available.

Comment: It's probly a mistake to treat infinitive purpose clauses with _in order_ the same way as tensed _because_ clauses. Changing from an infinitive to a tensed clause already changes the structure plenty. And as several people have pointed out, the semantic ranges of these two clause introducers overlap only partially. But that partial overlap is very difficult to specify, so a useful rule for exploiting the semantic similarity will not be forthcoming soon.

Comment: @John Lawler Not one for your _Basic Grammar_, then.

Answer (score 2):

**I have one counter example below. (Plus many more in the same format.)**

But first, I would like to note an opposite problem: The **semantics** can always be (closely) preserved when going from **because** to **in order to** (usually requiring a complicated transformation), but it cannot always be preserved when going from **in order to** to **because**.  This is because *an arbitrary reason including desire or necessity* is injected into the sentence where there is none given.

**I think the following sentence is a counter-example; I also show various attempts to use "because":**

► "**In order to** make tea, it is necessary for one to soak the tea bag in hot water." ◄

- **1a) Because one wants to** make tea, it is necessary for one to soak the tea bag in hot water. *(Incorrect semantics. See 1d.)*

  **1b) Because of the need to** make tea, it is necessary for one to soak the tea bag in hot water. *(Incorrect semantics. See 1d.)*

  **1c) Because of the process required to** make tea, it is necessary for one to soak the tea bag in hot water. *(Incorrect semantics. See 1d.)*

  **1d) Because of the process required to oxygenate blood, it is necessary for one to breathe.**  *(Note this "requires" that one must breathe for the given reason.  Likewise, sentences **1a, 1b,** and **1c** all "require" that one makes tea!)*

In the counter-example's description of the process, there is *neither a reason nor a necessity* to make tea.  Changing **in order to** into **because** *injects a reason* which coerces an odd semantic meaning: "the *reason* for making tea *necessitates* making tea."

I have to say, this was more of a tricky puzzle to manufacture such a sentence around a small jigsaw shape between the semantics of **because** and **in order to** to find this exception. As someone said, **in order to** nearly always implies volition, so this use is limited.

But not unheard of. **Like they say, "In order to make omletes, you have to crack a few eggs." And now that I've got the pattern down, if this holds then [here's dozens more with a similar format.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22in+order+to+succeed+you%22+OR+%22in+order+to+succeed+economic%22+OR+%22in+order+to+succeed+a+company%22)**

## **☺**

---

**Backstory:** The OP Question was motivated by [my comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/22934/how-to-ask-a-question-according-to-the-specific-sections#comment-43268) to [@msam's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/22966/3796) on ell.se. I suggested a counter-example probably existed:

> The one-way conversion rule is holding up ***because we're limiting our sentence form***:
>
> - "I did X **because** <reason>"
> - "I did Z **in order to** <goal>".
>
> Then one can substitute:
>
> - I did Z **because I wanted/needed to achieve** <goal>.
>
>   OR MORE GENERALLY:
> - I did Z **in order to** <goal> **because I wanted/needed to achieve** <goal>
>
> where **"wanted/needed to"** is a universal reason behind all human actions.
>
> ***Is this applicable to all sentence forms containing "in order to"? I doubt it.***

Comment: "In order to exist" in the second sentence is a dangling modifier, as the subject of the second clause is *parents*, not *one*.

Comment: Great catch @phenry.  Original sentence ("In order to exist, one's parents must exist.") fixed!

Comment: Yes; this is a more general sense of 'in order to' meaning 'for it to be possible to' rather than 'for the purpose of'. Good spot.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the logic in your second example. I still exist, despite both my parents being dead. But according to the example; to continue existing, one must have (present tense) parents.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - You are correct, and I fixed this to "must have had".  But note, even this could be debatable on some argument. And the sentence about the tea is not true in an absolute sense either. The point is to create a plausible sentence form that proves a grammatical exception to the OP "rule".

Comment: While this definitely shows the weakness of the statement, I'm not sure that it holds. Changing "the requirement" to "the process required" introduces a change in meaning (in c and d) - "Because of the requirement to excavate gold, the environment is polluted" vs "Because of the process required to excavate gold, the environment is polluted" - same outcome but not exactly the same (this cannot be converted directly to "in order to" since it shows a consequence not a purpose, just trying to indicate the change in meaning)

Answer (score 0):

It would always be this way, as you do [X] in order to do [Y], or [x] happens in order for [Y] to happen. This means you can reconstruct the sentence with **because** where necessary.

[In order to](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/in+order+to)

*Idiom*

> in order to, as a means to; with the purpose of: She worked summers in
>   order to save money for college.

Comment: I think so too, and see it as a logical conclusion, but I'm wondering whether this is actually always the case or if there are exceptions